# Undefined method length issue

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create methods for `Enumerable#each` and `Enumerable#map`, called `my_each` and `my_map`.

But there is an issue when I try to yield to a block from `my_each` in `my_map` map, can somebody help me?

When I change `my_each` inside `my_map` for just `each`, it works

```
module Enumerable
  def my_each
   return self.to_enum :my_each unless block_given?
       for i in 0..self.length - 1
           yield(self[i])
       end
       return self
  end

   def my_map(proc=nil)
       return_array = Array.new
       return self.to_enum :my_map if !block_given? && proc.nil?
       self.my_each do |i|
           return_array.push(proc.call(i)) unless proc.nil?
           return_array.push(yield(i)) if block_given? && proc.nil?
       end
       return_array
   end
end



array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

puts '*** my_each ***'
array.my_each do |num|
  puts num * num
end

   puts '*** my_map ***'
puts "#{((1..4).my_map { |i| i * i })} "
puts "#{(1..4).my_map.to_a} "
puts "#{([1, 2, 3, 4].my_map { |i| i * i })} "
puts "#{[1, 2, 3, 4].my_map.to_a}\n\n\n"
```

it must work as a normal `map` method, but it throws me this:

```
undefined method `length' for 1..4:Range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're invoking `my_each` in a Range object. And seeing your code, there's no method `my_each` defined on the Range class.

As `my_map` doesn't implicitly call `to_a` in the receiver, then you're using the object "as is" within the `my_map` definition in:

```
def my_map(proc=nil)
  ...
  self.my_each do |i|
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

You can convert the receiver to an array and get rid of the error:

```
puts (1..4).to_a.my_map { |i| i * i }
# 1
# 4
# 9
# 16
```

Comment: thank you very much, to make it easier I replaced "self.my_each" with "self.to_a.my_each" :)